# How to get only the digits from list of string using java

Tags: java

I have list with combination of letters, digits and special characters. I need to extract the digits from string and store them in the same list.

I tried with below code

```
       List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
       list.add("132144, Test");
       list.add("76876295, Test2");
       //tried with replaceAll();
       list.replaceAll(x->x.replace("[^0-9]",""));
       //tried collection
       Collections.replaceAll(list, "\\W+", "");
       System.out.println(list);
```

Getting the output as [132144, Test,76876295, Test2], need output as [132144,76876295]

Comment: Do you want to include the `2` of the text `Test2` into the result?

Answer (score 3):

Stream the `list`, map each entry using a *regular expression* (`\\D` matches non-digits) to replace all non-digits with nothing. Collect that back into your original `list` (assuming you need to keep the new values only). Like,

```
list = list.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[132144, 768762952]
```

Your current input doesn't have such a case, but you might also filter out any empty `String`(s) after applying the regex.

```
list = list.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+", ""))
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
    String line = "This order was32354 placed OK?8377jj";
    String regex = "[^\\d]+";

    String[] str = line.split(regex);

    for(int i=0;i<str.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
32354
8377
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    list.add("132144, Test");
    list.add("76876295, Test2");
    for(String s:list)
        list1.add(retriveDigits(s));
    System.out.println(list1);
}

private static String retriveDigits(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("[^0-9]*", "");

}
```

}

Please find above class, I think that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NumberUtils.isNumber()` in stream like this:

```
list = list.stream()
           .filter(NumberUtils::isNumber)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```